# Ordenar pelo número de repetições de uma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Em uma consulta no MySql eu preciso selecionar os resultados e ordenar os resultados com base na quantidade que os mesmos se repetem usando a coluna `id_livro`, por exemplo:

Minha tabela comentários:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id_livro       | comentario  |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | Com1        |
+----------------+-------------+
|     1          | Com2        |
+----------------+-------------+
|     2          | Com3        |
+----------------+-------------+
|     3          | Com4        |
+----------------+-------------+
|     3          | Com5        |
+----------------+-------------+
|     3          | Com6        |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Dessa forma eu gostaria de organizar uma pesquisa que retorne os livros mais comentados em ordem descendente dos mais comentados para os menos comentados que no caso seria o livro 3, 2 e o 1

Como ficaria essa consulta?
Ps: Os resultados precisam ser agrupados pelo id do livro também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só colocar um `COUNT` dos registros e um `ORDER BY` no final:

```
SELECT id_livro,
       COUNT(id_livro) AS quantidade
  FROM comentarios
 GROUP BY id_livro
 ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado Sorack exatamente o que eu precisava, vou abrir outra pergunta mais ou menos do mesmo jeito, espero que possa me ajudar lá também tu sempre me salva quando o assunto é mysql

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que você tenha duas tabelas, uma para livros e outra para comentários, você poderia fazer assim:

Tabela `livro`:

```
CREATE TABLE livro (
    id INT,
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

INSERT INTO livro VALUES(1, "livro a");
INSERT INTO livro VALUES(2, "livro b");
INSERT INTO livro VALUES(3, "livro c");
INSERT INTO livro VALUES(4, "livro d");
```

Tabela `comentario`:

```
CREATE TABLE comentario (
    id INT,
    livro_id INT,
    comentario VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(livro_id) REFERENCES livro(id)
)

INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(1, 1, "comentario 11");
INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(2, 1, "comentario 12");
INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(3, 2, "comentario 21");
INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(4, 2, "comentario 22");
INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(5, 2, "comentario 23");
INSERT INTO comentario VALUES(6, 3, "comentario 31");
```

Select:

```
SELECT l.nome,
       count(c.id) AS numero_de_comentarios FROM livro l
LEFT JOIN comentario c ON l.id = c.livro_id
GROUP BY c.livro_id
ORDER BY numero_de_comentarios DESC;
```

Saída:

```
+------------+-----------------------+
| nome       | numero_de_comentarios |
+------------+-----------------------+
| livro b    |                     3 |
| livro a    |                     2 |
| livro c    |                     1 |
| livro d    |                     0 |
+------------+-----------------------+
```